# mysql_connect()

Tags: php

Necesito agregar mas campos a este sistema de usuario simple pero me aparece un error:

> "ha ocurrido un error y no se registraron los datos."

```
 <?php
    include('acceso_db.php'); // incluimos el archivo de conexión a la Base de Datos
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <?php
        if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) { // comprobamos que se han enviado los datos desde el formulario
            // creamos una función que nos parmita validar el email
            function valida_email($correo) {
                if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9-_.+%]+@[A-Za-z0-9-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/', $correo)) return true;
                else return false;
            }
            // Procedemos a comprobar que los campos del formulario no estén vacíos
            $sin_espacios = count_chars($_POST['usuario_nombre'], 1);
            if(!empty($sin_espacios[32])) { // comprobamos que el campo usuario_nombre no tenga espacios en blanco
                echo "El campo <em>usuario_nombre</em> no debe contener espacios en blanco. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['usuario_nombre'])) { // comprobamos que el campo usuario_nombre no esté vacío
                echo "No haz ingresado tu usuario. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['usuario_clave'])) { // comprobamos que el campo usuario_clave no esté vacío
                echo "No haz ingresado contraseña. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif($_POST['usuario_clave'] != $_POST['usuario_clave_conf']) { // comprobamos que las contraseñas ingresadas coincidan
                echo "Las contraseñas ingresadas no coinciden. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(!valida_email($_POST['usuario_email'])) { // validamos que el email ingresado sea correcto
                echo "El email ingresado no es válido. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }else {
                // "limpiamos" los campos del formulario de posibles códigos maliciosos
                $usuario_nombre = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario_nombre']);
                $usuario_clave = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario_clave']);
                $usuario_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario_email']);
                $usuario_tel   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario_tel']);
                $usuario_dir   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario_dir']);
                $usuario_card  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario_card']);
                $usuario_exp   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario_exp']);
                $usuario_cvv   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario_cvv']);
                $usuario_birth = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario_birth']);
                // comprobamos que el usuario ingresado no haya sido registrado antes
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT usuario_nombre FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_nombre='".$usuario_nombre."'");
                if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
                    echo "El nombre usuario elegido ya ha sido registrado anteriormente. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
                }else {
                    $usuario_clave = md5($usuario_clave); // encriptamos la contraseña ingresada con md5
                    // ingresamos los datos a la BD

                    $reg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios ('usuario_nombre', 'usuario_clave', 'usuario_email', 'usuario_freg', 'usuario_tel', 'usuario_dir', 'usuario_card', 'usuario_exp', 'usuario_cvv', 'usuario_birth') VALUES ('".$usuario_nombre."', '".$usuario_clave."', '".$usuario_email."', '".$usuario_tel."', '".$usuario_dir."', '".$usuario_card."', '".$usuario_exp."', '".$usuario_cvv."', '".$usuario_birth."' NOW())");
                    if($reg) {    
                        echo "Datos ingresados correctamente.";
                    }else {
                        echo "ha ocurrido un error y no se registraron los datos.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }else {
    ?>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
            <label>Usuario:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="usuario_nombre" maxlength="15" /><br />
            <label>Contraseña:</label><br />
            <input type="password" name="usuario_clave" maxlength="15" /><br />
            <label>Confirmar Contraseña:</label><br />
            <input type="password" name="usuario_clave_conf" maxlength="15" /><br />
            <label>Email:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="usuario_email" maxlength="50" /><br />
            <label>Telefono:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="usuario_tel" maxlength="10" /><br />
            <label>Direccion:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="usuario_dir" maxlength="50" /><br />
            <label>card</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="usuario_card" maxlength="16" /><br />
            <label>exp:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="usuario_exp" maxlength="5" /><br />
            <label>cvv:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="usuario_cvv" maxlength="4" /><br />
            <label>birth:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="usuario_birth" maxlength="10" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Registrar" />
            <input type="reset" value="Borrar" />
        </form>
    <?php
        }
    ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **¿Por qué estas usando una extensión obsoleta para manejar tus datos?** La extensión `mysql.*` es bastante vulnerable, por eso ha sido descontinuada y desaparece en PHP 7. Se recomienda pasar a PDO o MySQLi. [Ver más info aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Hay un dato de mas en tu `INSERT`

```
$reg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios ('usuario_nombre', 'usuario_clave', 'usuario_email', 'usuario_freg', 'usuario_tel', 'usuario_dir', 'usuario_card', 'usuario_exp', 'usuario_cvv', 'usuario_birth') VALUES ('".$usuario_nombre."', '".$usuario_clave."', '".$usuario_email."', '".$usuario_tel."', '".$usuario_dir."', '".$usuario_card."', '".$usuario_exp."', '".$usuario_cvv."', '".$usuario_birth."'");
```

Exactamente despues de `$usuario_birth` donde agregas el `NOW()`